# HighChart type = area hover color change at several points

Tags: javascript, highcharts, hover, point, zones

I have a chart at Hover need to repaint the area as possible to implement?

```
https://jsfiddle.net/rn1t0uq3/1/
```

It should look like this

```
http://joxi.ru/gmvRlljTB1VEma
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into crosshairs?
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.crosshair

I'm not sure if it does exactly the effect you are looking for, but it is pretty close:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23'],
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    min: 0,
    opposite: true,
    tickWidth: 0,
    crosshair: {
        width: 75,
        color: 'blue',
        zIndex: 0
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rn1t0uq3/2/

Comment: Thx for answer, 
crosshair occupies the entire height, the height is limited to right there points

Comment: this example, not hover...
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/color-zones-zoneaxis-x/
and use date

Comment: So you need to place rectangle in backogrund or only line on xAxis (like in screenshot) ?